# Unable to fill div.innerHTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm facing a fairly strange issue. I'm using a typical contactform. The handling goes by the jQuery ajax solution. Everything goes well except the resultmessage. For some strange reason the browser won't show the provided innerHTML.

The resultdiv is nothing more than: `<div id="ResultContactForm"></div>`. Yup.. it's an empty div, unaffected by CSS just waiting for some data to show.

The jQuery code I'm using is (**updated by the given posts**):

```
$("#contact-formulier").live('submit', function(){
    var str = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type:   "POST",
        url:    "ajax.php?type=contact",
        data:   str,
        success: function(result){ 
            $("#ResultContactForm").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){                    
                if(result) {
                    $(this).html(
                        $('<span/>', {
                            style: 'color: #76c5f0',
                            html: $('<strong/>', {
                                text: 'Bedankt voor je bericht! We nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met je op!'
                            })
                        })
                    );
                    $(":input", "#contact-formulier")
                        .not(":button, :submit, :reset, :hidden")
                        .val("");
                } else {
                    $(this).html(
                        $('<span/>', {
                            style: 'color: #FF0000',
                            html: $('<strong/>', {
                                text: 'Alle velden zijn verplicht in te vullen.'
                            })
                        })
                    );
                }                   
            });
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

It all works because when i put some alerts in the `if{}else{}` part i get the messages. I've a `if(document.getElementById() == undefined)`, but it tells me the div exists.. which is true of course ;)

Am I overlooking something? I have the exact same (except for the binding-ID) script for another form on the page which works without any problems.

A live example can be found at http://vfw.ontdek5.nl/index.php at the contactpage. (The site is in Dutch).

Comment: You use `.html()` in the true case and `.innerHTML` in the false case...

Comment: @BoltClock, why did you write a correct answer as a comment?

Comment: I saw that, that was from my testing with the getElementById, replaced it with the correct code (which still isn't working..) Btw, in eighter case the div isn't filled with the resultmessage...

Comment: @AlexanderMP: Well I don't think it's the correct answer... just a correct fact.

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried

```
$(this).html("<span style='color:#FF0000;'><strong>Alle velden zijn verplicht in te vullen.</strong></span>");
```

Also replace double quotes with single quotes in `style='color:#FF0000;'`

Answer (score 0):

It is a [method](http://api.jquery.com/html/), not a property:

```
$(this).html('<span style="color:#FF0000;"><strong>Alle velden zijn verplicht in te vullen.</strong></span>');
```

EDIT: Your condition should compare `result` to the string value "true":

```
if(result == "true") {
    ...
```

Comment: also true, just saw that as well and changed it to its correct way. But still it isn't working ;) Sorry for the messy post..

Comment: the validation is correct, and it comes in the correct if/else section. From the php script a boolean is echo'd/returned, so I can't check it as a string ;) Thanks for you posts !

Answer (score 0):

I would try to improve your code like this:

```
if(result) {
    $(this).html(
        $('<span/>', {
            style: 'color: #76c5f0',
            html: $('<strong/>', {
                text: 'Bedankt voor je bericht! We nemen zo snel mogelijk contact met je op!'
            })
        })
    );
    $(":input", "#contact-formulier")
        .not(":button, :submit, :reset, :hidden")
        .val("");
} else {
    $(this).html(
        $('<span/>', {
            style: 'color: #FF0000',
            html: $('<strong/>', {
                text: 'Alle velden zijn verplicht in te vullen.'
            })
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: I've tried your neater markup, but without result. As you can see in the source (from the provided link).

Answer (score 0):

After giving your actual code a test-run, I've noticed your call to the PHP script is returning a value of `"1"` as a string. You're not testing against the actual return information at all. You have two options. Test against the string value `"1"` or pass back a JSON serialized object from your PHP method that looks like `{"success" : true}` or `{"success" : false}` and test against `result.success`.

Either way, use [Darin Dimitrov's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283338/unable-to-fill-div-innerhtml-with-jquery/5283384#5283384) changing the conditional test to `if (result == "1")`. You need to get rid of that `.ajaxComplete()` call. If you want to execute a handler unconditionally after the evaluation of success or error on your XHR, you want to use that as an option to the AJAX method called "complete," similar to how you construct "success." [See the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the complete list of options. Complete is the fifth option down.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I kinda gave this one up. This has been taken over 5 hours now and im sick of the frickin stupid simple thing getting to work :p Maybe later I'll try to update the innerHTML of a div... for now its working with an ugly alert...